# Selecting OSX SDK version in Eclipse and Makefiles

Tags: eclipse, macos, gcc, sdk, makefile

I have a development Mac running 10.5. This causes my apps to not work in 10.4 (Google "_nsdefaultrunloopmode tiger"). I read the solution is to install the 10.4 SDK and compile against that. I have it installed (at least I have /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk)

Now I can't find a way to actually use that - I'm doing two things:

1) Compiling a library (SDL) using Makefiles
2) Compiling the program using Eclipse

I can't find a way to specify the SDK version in either of these two scenarios. Documentation doesn't seem to mention how to do it, so I'm thinking I'm overlooking something obvious. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the commands issued by Xcode for a build with the 10.4 SDK selected you will see that gcc/g++ flags include:

```
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk
```

and

```
-mmacosx-version-min=10.4
```